# Is it acceptable to use the shorthand "PDEs" in the title of a paper?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soft-question

If I write a paper, is it acceptable for me to use a title like
"analysis of PDEs related to blah blah blah"
instead of
"analysis of partial differential equations related to blah blah blah"?

I intend on using in the abstract the words partial differential equations and writing (PDE) in brackets next to it. Is this reasonable? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this. The arXiv has 482 hits with "PDE" in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is acceptable. MathSciNet has almost 3000 papers with "PDE" or "PDEs" in the title, e.g., "Propagation of low regularity for solutions of nonlinear PDEs on a Riemannian manifold with a sub-Laplacian structure" or "Stability of elliptic PDEs with respect to perturbations of the domain".

But it is not common to use "analysis of PDE ..." in a title, because "analysis of" does not add new information. A reader will naturally assume that whatever object is mentioned in the title is being  analyzed/investigated in the paper. (I know that "analysis"  also has a mathematical meaning, but it's such a loose/flexible meaning that the word still doesn't help to know what the paper is about.)

Also, writing "partial differential equations (PDE)" in the abstract will look a bit strange, unless your paper is intended for an undergraduate-research journal. If someone does not already know what PDE stands for, they have no business reading a research paper about them.

Comment: Thank you. Your last paragraph is interesting... I of course agree that if you don't know what PDE means you probably shouldn't read the paper but as a matter of formal English I thought it is better to introduce acronynms that one uses? Maybe not in this case..